# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

Why when I concatenate DataFrames my code shows this error?

I trained a model to detect and classify 6 classes, and then store the coordinates and probabilities of these classes in a DataFrame, but I also want to save all the probabilities of all classes, not just the maximum probability, I wrote this Function (below the important line of my code):

```
def prediction():
   ...
   table=[]
   ...
   table.append(np.array([[name], [x], [x+w], [y], [y+h]], ndmin = 2).reshape((1,5)))
   table = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(table))
   classes_probas=CNNmodel.predict(images)
   max_proba=classes_probas.argmax(axis = 1)
   classes_probas = list(classes_probas)
   max_proba = list(max_proba)
   #Add probas of each class to the table
   table['class1'] = classes_probas[0]
   table['class2'] = classes_probas[1]
   table['class3'] = classes_probas[2]
   table['class4'] = classes_probas[3]
   table['class5'] = classes_probas[4]
   table['class6'] = classes_probas[5]
   table["max_proba"] = max_proba
   return table
```

After I call the function "predictions":

```
table= pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','Xmin','Xmax','Ymin','Ymax','class1','class2','class3','class4','class5','class6','max_proba'])
table=prediction()
```

But when I run my code, it shows this error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: Why do you create the dataframe "table" and then set it to be an empty string inside the function prediction? Also please provide the full traceback, i.e. showing the line of code where this error occurs.